# Regex 3last characters are exactly -2D or -3D

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write patter that 3 last characters are -2D or -3D 
for example xxxxxxx-3D
I try something like that

```
^(-3D|-2D){3}$
```

-2D or -3D may have random prefix

Comment: Try `^.*-[23]D$`

Comment: I'm not at my desk, so this is just on the fly.  I always test my regexes out before using them. Did you try `^.*(-3D|-2D)$`

Comment: thx it's work Marathon and when D letter is lower case or upper ?

Comment: Then `^.*-[23][Dd]$`

Comment: @K.AlanBates ^.*(-3D|-2D)$ this pattern work

Comment: @Wojciech Abacki if you care which pattern matched (it can only match either -2D$ or -3D$ after all) then the parentheses around the test tokens will provide you that information.If all you care about is to predicate some processing on the condition that the input match the prescribed pattern and you have no conditions driven by the "2" vs the "3" then no capture group will be necessary.In such a simple regex though, I prefer explicit tests for simplicity.In this case, it won't really matter. In more complex regexes, it might.Try to keep your regexes expressive until you need performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{3}$` will restrict to repeat following pattern three time in above case `-2D-2D-2d OR -3D-3D-3D`

use 
`^.*(-3D|-2D)$`

.* matches any character (except for line terminators)

this will match characters `-2D OR -3D` followed by any string e.g 123asd-2D OR123asd-3D

Comment: Just `-[23]D$` is enough.

Comment: Mush provide | in between 2 and 3 like ^.*-[2|3]D$ this will also work for the above case

Comment: `-[2|3]D$` will also match `-|D`